# Vagrant performance on HTTP

Tags: phpunit, vagrant

I am seeing very slow vagrant performance, regardless of provider or number of cores I allocate.  Seems to be an issue with either OSX, Vagrant settings, or the VMWare Fusion / VirtualBox provider.

I run a PHPUnit testsuite, inside the VM it takes seconds.. outside it takes minutes.

[image]

How can I optimize HTTP performance ?  I'm already utilizing NFS.

Comment: First of all, it's either OSX or VMWare / Virtualbox. vagrant is a wrapper and as soon as your box is booter, vagrant is not involved anymore. Second of all I am wondering how you can run PHPUnit outside of the VM and how it does involve the vm at all. Can you elaborate on this one?

Comment: @Sgoettschkes phpunit was run in OSX because it didn't rely anymore on the codebase it was running against.  It just simply fires cURL requests